# XPages - styling a fieldset/legend tag

Tags: css, xpages, fieldset

I'm experimenting with some fieldset designs that I found online and trying to implement them in XPages.

My XPages app is using the oneUI V2.1 theme. I'm loading a custom css file via the XPages Resources section. I've added the class for the fieldset and legend tags in there but they do not seem to be taking.

If I style it inline, it works great so I know its either how I've defined it in the CSS file or how I'm calling it.

Would someone be so kind and point out my mistake? My source code follows:

XPages:

```
<xp:view xmlns:xp="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/core"
xmlns:xc="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/custom">
<xp:this.resources>
    <xp:styleSheet href="/phc.css"></xp:styleSheet>
</xp:this.resources>
<xc:cc_fieldset legendText="My first legend">
    <xp:this.facets>
        <xp:panel xp:key="facetFieldSetContent">
            <xc:cc_incident></xc:cc_incident>
        </xp:panel>
    </xp:this.facets>
</xc:cc_fieldset>
</xp:view>
```

Custom Control:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xp:view xmlns:xp="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/core"
xmlns:xc="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/custom">

<!--  fieldset style="border-radius: 5px; padding: 5px; min-height:150px; border:8px solid #1f497d; background-color:#eeece1;"-->
    <!--  legend style=" margin-left:20px;background-color:#1f497d; padding-left:10px; padding-top:5px; padding-right:120px; padding-bottom:5px; ; color:white; border-radius:15px; border:8px solid #eeece1; font-size:40px;" -->
    <section>
    <fieldset styleClass="lotusTable fieldset"> 
        <legend styleClass = "lotusTable fieldset legend">
        <xp:text escape="false" id="legendText"
            value="#{javascript:compositeData.legendText}">
        </xp:text>
    </legend>
    <xp:callback facetName="facetFieldSetContent"
        id="callbackFieldControlSet" />
    </fieldset>
    </section>
```

CSS:

```
.lotusTable fieldset {
font-family: sans-serif;
border: 5px solid #1F497D;
background: #ddd;
}

.lotusTable fieldset legend {
background: #1F497D;
color: #fff;
padding: 5px 10px ;
font-size: 32px;
border-radius: 5px;
box-shadow: 0 0 0 5px #ddd;
margin-left: 20px;
}
```

Comment: don't know about `xpage` but you no need to write a so complex CSS to style the `fieldset` and `legend`. check the example. http://jsbin.com/zenuheqo/1/edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change styleClass to class (since you are writing HTML directly and not XPages XML). So do this instead:

```
<section>
<fieldset class="lotusTable fieldset"> 
    <legend class="lotusTable fieldset legend">
    <xp:text escape="false" id="legendText"
        value="#{javascript:compositeData.legendText}">
    </xp:text>
</legend>
<xp:callback facetName="facetFieldSetContent"
    id="callbackFieldControlSet" />
</fieldset>
</section>
```

Comment: Thanks Per. That was it. I also had to change the Css class to lotusForm before it actually worked.

Comment: <section>
    <fieldset class="lotusForm fieldset"> 
    <legend class="lotusForm fieldset legend">
    <xp:text escape="false" id="legendText"
        value="#{javascript:compositeData.legendText}">
    </xp:text>
</legend>
<xp:callback facetName="facetFieldSetContent"
    id="callbackFieldControlSet" />
</fieldset>
</section>